# Javascript: function that link to the button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want to alert a warming when some information submitted by the user isn't right when they try clicking on the button.

```
<span class="error">*</span>
<label for="email"><span class="register">E-mail</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="emailInfo"></span>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required" onkeyup="emailCheck()">

<button type="submit" id="button" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="buttonCheck()"><span>Submit</span></button>

<script>
function emailCheck() {
            var emailReg=/^([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])(\w|\-)+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/;
            var address=document.getElementById("email").value;

            if (!emailReg.test(address)) {
                document.getElementById("emailInfo").innerHTML="<font color='red'>The email address is available";
                document.getElementById("button").disabled=true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("emailInfo").innerHTML="";
                document.getElementById("button").disabled=false;
            }
        }

function buttonCheck() {
            if (document.getElementById("button").disabled) {
                alert("Please double check your info")
            }
        }
</script>
```

The button is actually disabled. However, nothing happened when I clicked the button.

Comment: Try to edit  your condition like that: if(document.getElementById("button").disabled == true){}

Answer (score 1):

You can't capture a `click` event on a button that's disabled. What you could do is try to "simulate" the appearance of a disabled button using CSS, and then capture the click event.

For example, you might create a `disabled` class in CSS:

```
.disabled {
      background-color: #DDD;
      color: #999;
}
```

Here's a full example using your code:

```js
function emailCheck() {
  var emailReg = /^([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])(\w|\-)+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/;
  var address = document.getElementById("email").value;

  if (!emailReg.test(address)) {
    document.getElementById("emailInfo").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>The email address is available";
    document.getElementById("button").classList.add("disabled");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("emailInfo").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("button").classList.remove("disabled");
  }
}

function buttonCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById("button").classList.contains('disabled')) {
    alert("Please double check your info")
  }
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  background-color: #DDD;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<span class="error">*</span>
<label for="email"><span class="register">E-mail</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="emailInfo"></span>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required" onkeyup="emailCheck()">

<button type="submit" id="button" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="buttonCheck()"><span>Submit</span></button>
```

Comment: That is amazing. But I am new to JavaScript. There is something I don't understand in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled form controls doesn't react to click events.
In your example, a user clicking the button will never fire the event.

You can, however, change the styles of the button to make it look like it's disabled, but I wouldn't recommend that, since users tend to trust their previous knowledge of how things work.

The best approach is keep the button enabled at all times and alert the user on click, or removing/disabling the button, but keep a message above it explaining *why* the button is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can't click when the button is disabled. And when someone tries to click the button for the first time before entering the email I hope the alert should be shown. I just changed your logic a little bit. I think this is what you want.
And I have put a better email validation expression for you as well.

```js
function emailCheck() {
            var emailReg  = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
            var address=document.getElementById("email").value;
           
            if (emailReg.test(address)) {
                document.getElementById("emailInfo").innerHTML="<font color='red'>The email address is available";
                document.getElementById("button").disabled=false;
            } 
            else {
               document.getElementById("emailInfo").innerHTML="";
               
           }
        }

function buttonCheck() {
        var emailReg  = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        var address=document.getElementById("email").value;
        
        if(!emailReg.test(address)){
            document.getElementById("button").disabled=true;
            alert("Please double check your info");
        }
      
}
```

```html
<span class="error">*</span>
<label for="email"><span class="register">E-mail</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="emailInfo"></span>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required" onkeyup="emailCheck()">

<button type="submit" id="button" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="buttonCheck()"><span>Submit</span></button>
```